# OffsetDateTime date object not getting stored in db the way date is set in object

Tags: java, postgresql, kotlin, datetime, java-time

I have a model which has startDateTime field which is storing DateTime in OffsetDateTime format.

```
startDateTime: 2023-07-25T04:40:46.143-08:00
```

However when we store the above object in our PostgreSQL db on GCP, it is getting stored in below format:
`2023-07-25 12:40:46.143+00`

It looks like it is adjusting the above object to UTC time.
But my requirement is, it sohuld store in the same format which is there in object and **should not adjust** to UTC time.

I explored the methods given [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), but none of the methods is satisfying my requirement.

Can someone please suggest if there is a way to acheive this. Any help would be appreciated.

Code I used and input is `startDateTime: 2023-07-25T12:40:46.143Z`
and `"timeZoneOffset": "UTC-08:00"`. I am converting input to expected OffsetDateTime based on timezoneOffset value.

```
 val actualDateTime: OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(startDateTime)
            val zoneOffset: ZoneOffset = ZoneOffset.of(timeZoneOffset.replace("UTC", ""))
            val expectedDateTime: OffsetDateTime = actualDateTime.withOffsetSameInstant(zoneOffset)
            return expectedDateTime.toString()
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRANSACTION
(
    id                uuid                     DEFAULT,
    start_date_time   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    end_date_time     TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    currency          VARCHAR(5)               NOT NULL,
    country           VARCHAR(50)              NOT NULL,
    created_at        TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    created_by        VARCHAR (255)            NOT NULL,
    startDateTime     TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: please share relevant code and the ddl

Comment: I am new to this @Jens, please ask if you need additional info.

Comment: Your `startDateTime` cannot possibly be `"2023-07-25T12:40:46.143"`, otherwise `OffsetDateTime.parse(startDateTime)` would throw an exception because the time zone is missing.

Comment: Also please show the code that stores and retrieves the timestamps to/from the DB.

Comment: Typo error @k314159. To store in DB, we are using interface which has implemented `JpaRepository` and calling save methods to store in DB.

Comment: *TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE* but that's not what you've got..? You should probably store the offset separately since it would appear there's no timestamp with offset in PG

Comment: See the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html): "For `timestamp with time zone`, the internally stored value is always in UTC"... "When a `timestamp with time zone` value is output, it is always converted from UTC to the current [`timezone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) zone".

Comment: Define your acronyms on first use. I imagine “GCP” is Google Cloud Platform, but can’t be sure.

Answer (score 5):

Your best practice is to think of time zone as a presentation attribute and the timestamp itself as an instant in time.  If your business need requires that you preserve the timezone of the input field, then you must store that in another field outside of the timestamp.

The type "timestamp with timezone" is used by postgresql only to interpret the timezone offset from an input string.  That timezone data is not preserved by the database.  The timestamp is always stored in UTC, and the time zone is immediately lost.

Comment: Interesting. That suggests the OP should be converting to `LocalDateTime`, saving that in TIMESTAMP WITHOUT OFFSET and storing the offset separately as seconds

Comment: If someone presents a string representation of date and time, it's parsed and stored in a long value of milliseconds since epoch, typically wrapped in some utility class like Instant (or DateTime in legacy code).  That is effectively UTC, which contains no time zone offsets and no adjustments for daylight saving time.  With only that long value, you can pair it with any time zone to present it in someone's local time.

Comment: *...typically wrapped in some utility class like Instant (or DateTime in legacy code)...* Actually if you parse the string input in the form *2023-07-25T04:40:46.143-08:00* with `Instant`, it will translate it into the UTC form represented by that offset and the offset will therefore be lost and the timestamp adjusted

Comment: Rather than thinking of it as first translating a text-based date with an offset or specifier into another text-based date in "UTC form", I find it easier to think of any qualified date as having enough data for a parser to translate it directly into an internal representation of milliseconds since epoch.  All three representations, whether `Instant` or `DateTime` or `TIMESTAMP`, all boil down to that one long value wrapped in functionality that operates using that value.  It's never from timezone A to timezone B and always from timezone A to milliseconds since epoch to timezone B.

Answer (score 2):

> [Postgres] is adjusting the above object to UTC time.

Yes, that is how Postgres works. That is a feature, not a bug.

For the type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, any zone or offset info included with a submitted value is used to adjust “to UTC”, meaning an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC. The [Answer by phatfingers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77942344/642706) is correct.

> my requirement is … should not adjust to UTC time.

If you want to record a moment, a specific point on the timeline, while preserving the original offset, in Postgres you have these choices:

- Use a textual type like `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` to record a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Such strings will be in chronological order when sorted alphabetically as long as you (a) use the same resolution (seconds, microseconds, etc.), and (b) avoid the use of the `Z` abbreviation of `+00:00`.
- Store the date-time portion in a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` (note the `WITHOUT` rather than `WITH`), along with storing the offset as text in standard IOS 8601 format or storing the offset as a signed number, perhaps a number of seconds.

Sorting does not work with that second option. So you might need to denormalize your table, to redundantly store the same moment as a UTC value in an extra column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

However, if I were on your team, I’d be asking if you truly need to keep that original offset.

And be aware that doing date-time math to move into the past/future using offsets may be faulty as you would be ignoring changes made to the offset by the implicit time zone. For date-math, always prefer time zone over offset.

Definitions:

- An **offset** is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead/behind UTC.
- A **time zone** is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

---

Programming by intuition is risky. You really should study the documentation before using a data type.

In particular, **databases vary radically in their date-time handling** capabilities and behaviors. The SQL standard does little more than mention the names of a several possible data types — and even that little they botched.

So every database engine does their own thing. Be careful. Study the doc. Experiment and practice.